# In Powershell, what is the proper way to select data from a FormatTable to manipulate it as a string?

Tags: powershell

So, I have a specific situation where I am trying to get a list of all enabled tasks from Windows Task Schedule and dump them to the file.  This is how far I've gotten so far:

```
schtasks /QUERY /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv | where { $_."Next Run Time" -ne "Disabled" } | ft -HideTableHeaders TaskName
```

That will give me a list of tasks, but they all start with a '\', so I want to do a SubString(1) on each of the values before capturing the results to a file.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

If I try something like this:

```
select "$_".SubString(1)
```

I just get something like:

```
icrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
```

Which, is a SubString of the class name, but I can't figure out how to get the SubString of the value of the object.

Comment: Manipulate if _BEFORE_ you use `ft` as it destroys what little objects you have. If you must then you could `ft | Out-string`. Would have to play with your example more to know for sure

Comment: Fomrt-Table was not meant to be manipulated in that sense. Its only purpose is to provide a quick and easy way to output data to the console in a table format. If you are just trying to remove the header use `Select -Skip 1` instead of your `ft` command.

Comment: @NewGuy That alone would not work. It is already an object array and not a string array. What you suggest would skip a value not the header.

Comment: @Matt Indeed, I misread a bit and had recently used `ConvertTo-Csv` where I wanted to remove the headers so I guess that was already on the brain.

Comment: I would not recommend the `schtasks.exe` command for dumping information about scheduled tasks because it can be a nuisance to parse correctly. The `TaskService` COM object is a better choice, IMO. Details in the article [Use PowerShell to Report on Scheduled Tasks](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/how-use-powershell-report-scheduled-tasks).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart in PowerShell v3 and newer, there's `Get-ScheduledTask` so you don't even need to use the COM object.

Comment: Not PowerShell v3, but rather newer OS (I believe those cmdlets first appeared in Windows 8/Server 2012 and newer). For older OS, we can use the COM object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would also work in your case

```
(schtasks /QUERY /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv | where { $_."Next Run Time" -ne "Disabled" -and $_.TaskName -ne "taskname" } | Select -ExpandProperty Taskname) -replace "^\\"
```

Had to add `$_.TaskName -ne "taskname"` as the output contained headers over and over again. That was an easy was to remove them. Use select to extract the tasknames and then just replace the leading slash. `-replace` works on arrays so we wrap up the results from `schtasks`

If you can avoid it, which is usually easy, *NEVER* try and manipulate data from `Format-*`. Their primary function is for displaying data on screen only.

The format cmdlets return `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData` objects, not strings, which is what you were running into. You can get around it by piping to `Out-String` if you like the layout. That would be the only reason.

Every time you try to process the raw data from `Format-Anything` I cry a little inside.

**About schtask**

I already account for one anomaly about the output with the `where` clause but there could be other issues with the output. Read the blog article by [Bill_Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102693/bill-stewart) on how to : [Use PowerShell to Report on Scheduled Tasks](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/how-use-powershell-report-scheduled-tasks)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Win8/Server 2012 or higher, use this:

```
Get-ScheduledTask | where-object{$_.state -ne "disabled"} | select-object TaskName
```